# forEach not working in several older browsers that should have support

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm trying to figure out why Safari 9 throws up an error with the below code:

```
const features_blocks = document.querySelectorAll('#feature-blocks .block');
features_blocks.forEach(f => {
// do something here
});
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: features_blocks.forEach is not a function
```

I also see it on some older firefox versions, and Chrome 49 (just the 3 I noticed in our error tracker). Is there something I'm doing wrong? CanIUse seems to suggest forEach is supported in all these versions:

https://caniuse.com/?search=foreach

Comment: CanIUse says that `NodeList.forEach` isn't supported until Safari 10, Chrome 51 and FireFox 50. See https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_nodelist_foreach

Comment: A NodeList is not the same as an array - older environments don't have `NodeList.prototype.forEach`

Comment: Use `[].forEach.call(features_block, ...)`

Comment: @Barmar thanks - this seems to do it: `[].forEach.call(features_blocks, function(f) { observer_features.observe(f); } )`